# MySQL ODBC connection won't work

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

How can I test my mysql connection using inno setup before the installation process?

I have my current connection string as

> 'Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=database; User=root;    ...using ADODB.connection

But it is not working, I get an error

> Provider not found and no default driver specied

I downloaded a lot of providers just to catch up this error, but no one is working.

Comment: Show us your code! + What providers did you test and how? "downloading" is hardly enough.

Comment: Around so. See, how better it looks now. Also you could do this. I hope you will.